# How to disable USB devices based on vendor ID in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, vendor-id

I want to disable USB devices based on vendor ID in Linux, and allow only specific devices to be used. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to blacklist or whitelist? Different answers might apply.

Comment: thank you for replying, what is diff b/w them? i want to allow only specif vendor usb's.

Comment: blacklist - block only specific; whitelist - allow only specific. Let me see if I can figure it out now

Answer (score 2):

When you connect a usb device to your PC, a service called `udev` manages the work of connecting it, enabling the appropriate driver, etc. To do what you need to do, you need to write `udev` rules to control its behaviour.

You can look at [this article](http://www.linuxforu.com/2012/06/some-nifty-udev-rules-and-examples/) for some examples of how to control it. I am afraid I don't know it in enough detail to explain how to achieve what you want particularly, but `udev` is the answer.